# Como puedo editar los permisos de Drive?

Tags: drive

Tengo un problema. Yo tengo una carpeta de drive con muchos archivos dentro. Lo que yo quiero hacer es poder compartir esta carpeta con otras personas y que estas puedan ver los archivos y descargarlos y que tambien puedan subir archivos si quieren. Lo único que no quiero que hagan estas personas a las que les comparto la carpeta es poder eliminar archivos. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que no puedes hacer eso. Las únicas opciones que da Drive son: Lector y Escritor. O solo lees o tienes control total. Por cierto, esta pregunta no es sobre programación así que será cerrada.